# Handling different types when unmarshalling a json

Tags: json, go, decode

I'm consuming an endpoint (which I don't own and I cannot fix) and this endpoint returns JSON.

The problem is this JSON can come in different formats:

Format 1:

```
{
  "message": "Message"
}
```

or

```
{
  "message": ["ERROR_CODE"]
}
```

Depending on what happened.

I'd like to have one struct to hold this response so later I can check if the `message` is a string or array, and properly follow a flow.

Is it possible to do it in Go? The first approach I thought was to have two structs and try to decode to the one with `string`, and if an error happens, try to decode to the one with `array`.

Is there a more elegant approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unmarshal it into a value of `interface{}` type, and use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) or [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) to inspect the type of value it ends up. Note that by default JSON arrays are unmarshaled into a value of type `[]interface{}`, so you have to check for that to detect the error response.

For example:

```
type Response struct {
    Message interface{} `json:"message"`
}

func main() {
    inputs := []string{
        `{"message":"Message"}`,
        `{"message":["ERROR_CODE"]}`,
    }

    for _, input := range inputs {
        var r Response
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &r); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        switch x := r.Message.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println("Success, message:", x)
        case []interface{}:
            fmt.Println("Error, code:", x)
        default:
            fmt.Println("Something else:", x)
        }
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/akMKKo79_7R)):

```
Success, message: Message
Error, code: [ERROR_CODE]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom type that implements `json.Unmarshaller` and tries to decode each possible input format in turn:

```
type Message struct {
    Text string
    Codes []int
}

func (m *Message) UnmarshalJSON(input []byte) error {
    var text string
    err := json.Unmarshal(input, &text)
    if err == nil {
        m.Text = text
        m.Codes = nil
        return nil
    }

    var codes []int
    err := json.Unmarshal(input, &codes)
    if err == nil {
        m.Text = nil
        m.Codes = codes
        return nil
    }

    return err
}
```

I prefer this approach over unmarshalling into `interface{}` and type-asserting later because all the type checks are encapsulated in the unmarshalling step.

For a real-world example, check out my `type veryFlexibleUint64`: https://github.com/sapcc/limes/blob/fb212143c5f5b3e9272994872fcc7b758ae47646/pkg/plugins/client_ironic.go

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a different type for **Message** and making that implement `json.Unmarshaller`

here is how the code would be

```
type message struct {
    Text  string
    Codes []string //or int , assuming array of string as it was not mentioned in the question
}

func (m *message) UnmarshalJSON(input []byte) error {
    if len(input) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    switch input[0] {
    case '"':
        m.Text = strings.Trim(string(input), `"`)
        return nil
    case '[':
        return json.Unmarshal(input, &m.Codes)
    default:
    return fmt.Errorf(`invalid character %q looking for " or [`, input[0])

    }
}

type Error struct {
    Message message `json:"message"`
}
```

You may find full code with test [here](https://play.golang.com/p/RMjSVVsYgeF)